# Watson Assistant Upload file

Tags: upload, ibm-cloud, chatbot, ibm-watson, watson-assistant

I have built a Chatbot using Watson Assistant, and I am looking for a way to **enable the user to upload a pdf** or an image in the chat, like using an `Upload File` button, or a `Drag and drop or files here` functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Watson Assistant on IBM Cloud is a conversation service that can interact with other components of a solution. Depending on the type of [Watson Assistant integration](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/assistant?topic=assistant-deploy-integration-add), uploading a file is possible, or not. You might want to check out [custom integrations](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/assistant?topic=assistant-deploy-custom-app) which would allow you to build such file uploading feature around the chatbot capability.

Note that the [chatbot API](https://cloud.ibm.com/apidocs/assistant/assistant-v2) is designed for driving dialogs by exchanging messages. The file upload would be on top.

Comment: Yes, I have seen this answer before.

Answer (score 0):

File upload will be an additional feature of functionality that you will have to have in the custom UI and integrate it with the Orchestration/Integration Layer and then do whatever you want to do with that file and then send the required information from the file to Watson Assistant in a context variable.