# Upload file functionality and sent it to server via REST API IBM ChatBot

Tags: integration, chatbot, watson-assistant

I have built a chatbot using IBM Watson and using dialog skills. I have also used Webhook for getting data from external server. I have a use case where I need to upload file in dialog conversation. There is no direct way to achieve this in IBM Watson Assistant AFAIK.

How to achieve this? I am integrating this chatbot one of the web application UI Page.

Please let me know if any one of you have implemented before?

Thanks
Kumar Shorav

Comment: See my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62532598/watson-assistant-upload-file/62533802#62533802

Answer (score 0):

You need to build an application layer to orchestrate between the chatbot interface, external servers, and IBM watson.
You can use something like [Microsoft Bot Framework](https://dev.botframework.com) or [BotKit](https://botkit.ai) as a base for the application layer, and develop your logic within it.